# How do you work with resource ownership with adonis-acl

Tags: acl

How do you manage the owner of a resource when using `adonis-acl`? In my application the typical pattern is that if you own the resource you have full `CRUD` over it but Admins also have `Updated` and `Delete` control over the resource even though they are not the owners.

Ideally I want to manage this control though middleware rather than having to then re-check ACL in my Controllers. Ideally I'm looking for something like

```
Route
   .get('/users')
   .middleware(['auth:jwt', 'is:(administrator)' 'can:read_resouce_{SOMEKINDOFID}'])
```

Currently is seems that the only way I can do this is to setup a permission for every single resource which for my use case seems unnecessary.

Thanks